# Set owner of NFT

Tags: nft

I'm new to smart contract I don't know is this a right question.
Is it possible that someone else mint the NFT but the owner of that NFT is the person who deployed the contract ?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR. Yes.

Non-Fungible Token is a concept. There are many implementations of that concept, and there's no limit on what you can implement.

Most of the NFTs in the Ethereum ecosystem follow the ERC20, ERC721, or ERC1155 specification, but those are interfaces and not specific implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There is many what ifs that could be written here.  Here's one I think of instantly.

If I understand your question, in theory it can happen. Lets say you are minting on a marketplace that automatically holds your NFT until it sells.  There are a couple phone apps that do this, like beyond mars.  This would mean that the minter or contract owner would be listed as owner until the NFT is transferred to the person who actually interacted with the smart contract.  Another many people misunderstand is lazy minting, which isnt minting at all and no one has an NFT until the sell.

Personal Opinion:
I am a founder of an NFT marketplace online. Shhhhh. I don't like the idea of me or someone that works for me, holding an artists artwork/NFT indefinitely.  For this reason we only hold it after the artist mints it and takes possession, then initiates a sell action with the smart contract themseves.  At which point they pay a small gas fee to transfer it to the contract and its held until it sells, expires or the artists cancels the sell.